# Error AADSTS650052 - Apps service principal access

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-service-principal

I am getting the below error message when my Application (A) is trying to access another application (B) which is hosted in a different Tenant. Both applications have been registered to support multi-tenant access (i.e Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows) within their respective tenant. The microsoft outlook account I am using is associated with both tenants. What am I missing?

'AADSTS650052: The app is trying to access a service 'xxx-xxxx-xxxx' that your organization 'xxx-xxx-xxx' lacks a service principal for. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions or consent to the application in order to create the required service principal.

Answer (score 0):

In order for an application to authenticate with a tenant, a service principal representing it must exist in that tenant. For multi-tenant apps this is created when you go through authentication to that app on the target tenant. So you need to do a login against your app with the target tenant as the authority.